Power efficiency between lower voltage BLDC or higher voltage BLDC and no SMPS
Glossary:

BLDC: Brushless DC motor
SMPS: Switch mode power supply

I was hoping if someone with some DC motor experience can assist me. What would be more power efficient? Going from 15 V to 6 V to drive a BLDC or using the 15 V to drive the BLDC. Does this have implications to the torque the motor can handle? Lower voltage = higher current (up to the point where the winding resistance sets the max current of course).

The output stage of a BLDC motor driver contains the same power switching paths and elements as a step down buck converter with sync FET.
As long as the mentioned step down ratio is only 2.5:1 and the supply voltage is only 15 V, there is no need to step down the voltage first, just limit the motor driver to only use up to 40% PWM and you have your maximum 6 V motor voltage with the same high current available as a separate buck converter would provide.
In this case there are no extra losses in a separate converter. This will be different at higher voltages or step down rates, where other aspects are relevant.
Another aspect is, that during forced spin down of the BLDC motor energy is fed back to the driver supply and the voltage will rise significant. This might damage a separate converter in front of the motor driver.

You make a compelling point. It also depends on it's operating point, but for my application I think we can perfectly fine run it at 15VDC. Thanks for the insight.

energy is fed back possible. voltage will rise [significantly] How? Once the inductive spike subsides, the EMF will be no higher than before: 6 V tops?

@greybeard Consider a buck converter with 2 FETs. This will as well act as boost converter in reverse direction if you appy the (in-)correct duty cycle.

You'd have to actively drive the switches for this effect - as in electrical braking/forced spin down.

@greybeard Yes, agreed. I could not exclude this. Well, my english could be better. Sometimes the correct expressions will not come up..
